# How to display an array by column in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32, masm32

I can display the array by row. I would like to understand how to display the array by column.

I created randomize number in to a single array.

How can I display the contents of array by column?

Currently my code

```
.code
push OFFSET array
push count
call disproc

disproc PROC
push ebp
mov  ebp, esp
...
...
...

mov eax,[esi]
call writedec
add esi, 4
loop
....
disproc ENDP
```

The output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

The desired output:

```
1 4 7 10
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

What should I consider?

Comment: I fixed your tags; this can't be x86-64 code because `push ebp` is not encodeable in long mode.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Irvine32 has cursor-movement functions.

Therefore you can only print out text from left to right, and *then* from top to bottom.  (Or if cursor-movement functions do exist, you don't have to use them for this.)

---

The solution is to figure out which array elements to print on each row, so you can figure out which order to print array elements in.

Assuming your array is `dd 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`, the order **you're printing is "column major" order like Fortran**, not row-major like C (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).

That means looping over the elements in a row involves incrementing the index by the number of rows.

You need to decide how many rows to use somehow, probably as an extra function arg.  Given that, **stride through the array by `4 * rows` bytes** to get the elements in that row.  You can detect the end of a row because your pointer address will be `>= array_end`.  Then you loop back to the start of the next row.

For example:  **untested**

```
array_square_print PROC
;; array pointer passed in       ESI   (clobbered)
;; column length = # of rows  in ECX   (clobbered)
;; total element count in        EDX   (clobbered)
    push  ebx
    push  edi    ; save some call-preserved registers

    lea   edx, [esi + 4*edx]     ; endp = one past the end  = array + n*size
    lea   ebx, [ecx * 4]         ; row_stride in bytes
    mov   edi, esi               ; start point for this row

@row_loop:
 @col_loop:
     mov   eax, [esi]
     add   esi, ebx               ; p += row_stride
     call  writedec 

     cmp   esi, edx
     jb   @col_loop               ; }while(p<endp);

    add   edi, 4                  ; next row = advance down the column
    mov   esi, edi                ; p = rowstart

    dec   ecx
    jnz   @row_loop

    pop   edi     ; restore regs
    pop   ebx
    ret
array_square_print ENDP
```

I used a custom calling convention for convenience.  It's like fastcall but with a 3rd register arg (ESI).

It might be possible to use fewer registers, but I'm not seeing how at the moment.  (Of course we could leave something read-only on the stack without being inefficient, but we do have enough registers even for the outer-loop stuff.)